# When finish Activity in BehaviorSubject's subscribe, The application is crashed

Tags: android, android-intent, rx-java, rx-android, activity-finish

In 'subcribe' of 'BehaviorSubject', receive 'ArrayList' as a parameter to process data.
If you try to pass the accepted data into the Intent and finish it, the app is stopped.
What's the problem?

```
subject(requestData)
   .map(r->arrayList = r.getArrayList())
   .observeOn(Android.Schedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(r->{ finishWithData(r)});

private void finishWithData(r) {
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.putExtra("array", r);
   setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
   finish() // Here is Crash Point.
}
```

Comment: Closing such questions as duplicates of the canonical "My App has stopped" is not helpful.

Comment: Please add the exception including stack trace from logcat to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest getting `Disposable` from `BehaviorSubject` and dispose it in `onDestroy` of Activity.

```
Disposable disposable;


disposable = subject(requestData)
              .map(r->arrayList = r.getArrayList())
              .observeOn(Android.Schedulers.mainThread())
              .subscribe(r->{ finishWithData(r)});

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    disposable.dispose();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```